# Writing content to TemporaryFolder and deleting file after the test

Tags: java, junit, temporary-files

Im trying to write some strings to File created by TemporaryFolder.
I need to provide 3 Strings:
`Line1 a
Line2 b c
Line 3`

1) I make this, but it does not add anything. Length of `testedContent` is still 0. What am I making wrong? :

```
private ContentFileRetriever contentFileRetriever = new ContentFileRetrieverService();

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
    }

    @Test
    public void getContentFile() throws IOException {
        File textFile = tempFolder.newFile("testText.txt");
        String pathFile = textFile.getPath();
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(textFile.getName());
        fileWriter.write("Line1 a");
        fileWriter.write("Line2 b c");
        fileWriter.write("Line3 3");
        String[] testedContent = contentFileRetriever.getContentFile(pathFile);
        String[] expected = {"Line1 a", "Line2 b c", "Line 3"};
        assertArrayEquals(expected, testedContent);
    }
```

2) Should I do it in setup with `@Before` method or do it inside test?

3) I read that this folder will be deleted automatically, so I dont need to perform `.deleteOnExit()` on `textFile`?

Comment: Try flushing the writer and closing it using [OutputStreamWriter#flush](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#flush--) and [OutputStreamWriter#close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close--) methods of the OutputStreamWriter

Comment: @ValentinCarnu Added `fileWriter.flush();` before and after `fileWriter.write("Line1 a");` but still 0 length.

Comment: Try creating your `FileWriter` with your `File` object as a constructor parameter, and then flushing and closing it before reading from the file.`.

Comment: second thing I would try is to call `contentFileRetriever.getContentFile` method with `textFile.getAbsolutePath()` as parameter instead of `textFile.getPath()`

Comment: I have done: https://pastebin.com/jHGCTLTF and I have `testedContent.length = 1` I tried to flush for every writing to file, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems:

1. You open your FileWriter object with the name of the file instead of the file itself
2. You do not close your FileWriter

This works for me:

```
  @Test
  public void getContentFile() throws IOException {
    File textFile = tempFolder.newFile("testText.txt");
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(textFile);
    fileWriter.write("Line1 a");
    fileWriter.write("Line2 b c");
    fileWriter.write("Line3 3");
    fileWriter.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change textFile.*getName()* to textFile.*getPath()*, in the line where the **FileWriter** is created, as follows:

*From*

- FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(textFile.*getName()*);

*To*

- FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(textFile.***getPath()***);